# Calling PHP REST API from Android App doesn't display umlauts (äüö) correctly

Tags: php, android, mysql, okhttp

I've build a simple REST API in PHP which fires a query to my MySQL database (fully utf-8 encoded) and returns the result as a JSON array. In PHP I also set the charset to UTF-8: `mysqli_set_charset($con, "UTF8");`.

So when I call my Service like `http://<host>/getData.php` in my web browser I get something like this:

```
[{"id":"6","name":"föö","content":"bär"}]
```

which is totally correct.

Additionally I'm calling my REST Service out of my Android App using OkHttp3. But this always gives me the following output:

```
[{"id":"6","name":"f&ouml;&ouml;","content":"b&auml;r"}]
```

Obviously there is something wrong with the charset or something like that.

**Here is my JAVA code:**

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(config.getServerRoot() + php).newBuilder();

    String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    // Get a handler that can be used to post to the main thread
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            // Check for failure
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            }

            // Read data on the worker thread
            final String result = response.body().string();

            // result = [{"id":"6","name":"f&ouml;&ouml;","content":"b&auml;r"}]
        }
    });
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `&ouml;` is the html notation for `o umlaut`.

Comment: `&auml;` read `a uml` or `a umlaut` or `ä`

Comment: yeah, i know that

Comment: Then why do say `Obviously there is something wrong` ?

Comment: You can solve that by doing: `Html.fromHtml(result)`

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the Java bit? If you see the result in a browser then `&auml;` would be rendered as`ä` and therefore obscure the issue. Use something like curl or postman to see a raw response

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i got it! Renan Arceno reminded me, that my Rest Service is giving me HTML entities. So instead of using `Html.fromHtml(result)` in Java - which obviously works as well - I removed the PHP function `htmlentities()` which converts my characters to HTML entities.

Now it works. Thanks to you!